Inward-pointing normal vector into domain
Let $D$ be bounded planar domain, $\Gamma := \partial D \in C^2$. I feel vague on the definition of inward-pointing normal vector and think about it as follows. Avoiding first the general definition in some text of differential manifold, limited to the case of convex $\Gamma$ that the boundary curve will lie in one side of tangent line at each point $p \in \Gamma$, we start at the basic fact that the tangent gives normal vectors of opposite directions and define the inward-pointing normal vector as the one directed into the side mentioned above.
In this way, how can we prove that, for given $x \in \Gamma$ and  arbtrary small $\epsilon >0$, there exists a $\epsilon' \in (0, \epsilon)$ such that $x + \epsilon' n(x) \in D$, where $n(x)$ is the inward-pointing unit normal vector at point $x \in \Gamma$?

The last sentence is the definition of "inward."

@Moishe Kohan To illustrate the well-definedness of the last sentence, we should prove that there exists one normal vector which satisfies the need?

It depends on your definition of "normal" which you should spell out in your question.

I start at the tangent vector, the vectors of opposite directions which is orthogonal to the tangent is"normal".

Then there is continuum of normal vectors. Think again about your definition.

I  do not understand "continuum of normal vectors" you refer to. Could you help explain it?

Rescale your favorite normal vector...

What textbook on differential geometry are you reading?


Theodore Shifrin 2. John M. Lee


The $n(x)$ is a unit normal. I have no idea why "rescale" can help?

Once you assume "unit normal" (you said nothing about this before), the inward normal becomes unique. All this clarification should be in the body of your question, not in comments.

I made the supplements.

Reread the definition in Lee’s book. It is very clear and intuitive.

@peek-a-boo I am not familiar with terminology there since i research in the field of numerical analysis. I am thinking if we can give the property only using the rough definition?

then you won’t get a precise answer. Rough definitions only get rough answers. And in fact one of the ways of defining an inward pointing vector is to simply say that a vector $v$ is inward pointing at the point $x$ if there is an $\epsilon>0$ such that for all $t\in (0,\epsilon)$, we have that $x+tv\in D$. So, in this sense, there’s nothing to prove for your question. However you seem to not be satisfied by this approach, but I can’t help you further because you haven’t given a precise definition to compare this definition against.

@peek-a-boo I try to improve the version in your comment, thus, limited to the convex case, i attempt to give a better one in my thought. I am wondering if we can give the property with not so rigorous version as in John M. Lee.

but I still don’t understand what it is you find so unintuitive about the version in Lee. He says that at a boundary point, (non-zero) tangent vectors (which are velocity vectors of curves) come in three types: first is velocity of a curve $\gamma$ which is completely contained in the boundary. Second is of a curve $\gamma:(-\epsilon,0]\to M$, and third is velocity of a curve $\gamma:[0,\epsilon)\to M$. In the first case, the vectors are tangent to the boundary, in the second case, they are outward-pointing, and in the third case, inward-pointing. I suggest drawing pictures when $M=\Bbb{H}^n$…

… where $\Bbb{H}^n$ is the upper half-space; you can even take $n=2$ so you can fully draw pictures and reconcile the definition with intuition. It really does correspond very intuitively.

@peek-a-boo Let me follow you with some guesses. We can see the planar domain $D$ as the manifold $M$. For some $\epsilon >0$, there exists a smooth curve $\gamma: [0,\epsilon) \to M$ such that $\gamma(0) = x $, $\gamma'(0) = n(x)$. Now we have $\gamma(t) \in M$, $t \in [0,\epsilon)$, how can we give that $x + t n(x) \in M$?
